# Delete all the blanks in String before character with PHP

Tags: php

I have a string like this

```
$columnarray[$i] = "[blank][blank]Susanne 92 ASDLJK";
```

Do you think that my code is good enough for deleting the blanks before an letter starts?

```
$booleanValue = 1;
            while ($booleanValue == 1)
            {
                    $firstLetter = substr ($columnarray[$i], 0,1);
                    if ($firstLetter == " ") 
                    {
                        $columnarray[$i] = substr ( $columnarray[$i], 1);       
                    }
                    else 
                    {       
                        $booleanValue = 0;
                    }
            }
```

Comment: will trim be good enuf?

Comment: why dont you use `trim();`

Comment: you could have googled this much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`trim()`** is your best friend here !

```
$columnarray[$i]=trim($columnarray[$i]);
```

Well you could also use **`str_replace()`**. [*Not suggested in this scenario though*]

```
$columnarray[$i]=str_replace(" ","",$columnarray[$i]);
```

**EDIT :**

> But then I would delete also the rest of the blanks, but I just want
>   to delete the blanks in front of the letters

Make use of **`ltrim()`**

```
$columnarray[$i]=ltrim($columnarray[$i]);
```

Comment: using `str_replace` will strip all spaces even those within string.

Comment: @revo, Can you read what text i have put inside the square brackets (in italics) ?

Comment: if it's not needed do not give an example. `Sun like moon is a star but I don't suggest to call it moon though` [removed? :)]

Answer (score 0):

You must use trim to remove spaces

```
$columnarray[$i] = trim($columnarray[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "trim", you can also user RegEx.

```
preg_replace("#([\s])#", "", $columnarray[i]);
```

Comment: this will only strip the first white space.

Comment: $s = preg_replace('#([\s])#', "", "H e l l o");
    echo $s; // Returns Hello, just tested it.

Comment: As OP stated he doesn't want to remove spaces within string but at the beginning.

Comment: @revo, `As OP stated he doesn't` . What made you assume OP is a `he` ? O.o.

Comment: Ah, crap, true, should have read properly before posting. Its possible with RegEx too, but a bit more complicated.^^

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran everyone is male in the internet

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran didn't you have something more important to notice?! =))

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` function will delete the blanks at the start of your string and at the end of it.

If you want to remove only the left blanks (at the start) use `ltrim()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**ltrim()**](http://php.net/ltrim) function, this will strip spaces from the beginning of your string.

```
$str = "  test  ";
var_dump(ltrim($str)); // output: string(6) "test  "
```